# How to read from the default frame buffer after binding and unbinding an FBO with JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, bufferedimage, jogl, framebuffer

I use frame buffer objects in a JOGL application to do many things, from shadow maps to picking, and everything works as expected. However, as soon as I bind and unbind an FBO, errors are thrown when trying to get a screenshot of the default frame buffer and a null is returned.

I unbind an FBO by setting GL_FRAMEBUFFER to 0:

```
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

I then use AWTGLReadBufferUtil to get a BufferedImage (the true parameter at the end flips the image vertically):

```
new AWTGLReadBufferUtil(GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2), !renderBackgroundInScreenshot).readPixelsToBufferedImage(gl, true);
```

The following error occurs:

*GLReadBufferUtil.readPixels: readPixels error 0x502 1038x633*

It comes from [here](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/blob/master/src/jogl/classes/com/jogamp/opengl/util/GLReadBufferUtil.java#L237-L240). No error is found at any time before from glGetError().

When no FBO is bound or unbound, the BufferedImage is created without issue. I can also create BufferedImages from bound FBOs without issue. It is only when I unbind an FBO by setting GL_FRAMEBUFFER to 0 that I receive this error, so I am unsure how to get a screenshot from the default frame buffer after using an FBO. In fact, just calling gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); at the beginning of the render loop causes this error to occur.

To make things even weirder, if I use the following code to get the default frame buffer binding at the beginning of my render loop, 1 is returned. But setting GL_FRAMEBUFFER back to 1 does not fix this issue.

```
    int[] ifbodefault = new int[1];
    gl.glGetIntegerv(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, ifbodefault, 0);
    System.out.println(ifbodefault[0]);
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what is happening here?

Also, I use JOGL 2.3 and glGetError right before calling readPixelsToBufferedImage returns no errors.

I know of a possible workaround where I create yet another FBO for screenshots and render to that FBO and read from it when a screenshot is needed, but it seems like unnecessary overhead when I should just be able to read from the default frame buffer as I can when no FBO objects are used. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: You may want to try to do it manually, like [here](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/framework/Test.java#L444-L471)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that function only gives me a black image. I currently just implemented a workaround where textures generated from FBOs are just cached and then reused in the next render loop so I don't need to bind/unbind any FBOs when taking a screenshot. I am still looking into why this doesn't work though.

Comment: I removed the first of the two err.println (Info: GLReadBufferUtil.readPixels: pre-exisiting GL error 0x502 ) as the first was coming from my testing. I added the line number from the JOGL source where the second err originates.

Comment: 0x502 is 1282, that is `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, you can see [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) (at the end) all the possibility for which the code may fail

Comment: @elect I will continue to look into this, thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome, let us know if you get any news